# How to embed mermaid in html file?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown, sublimetext, mermaid

I have been using mermaid with sublimetext and MarkdownPreview, so I end up viewing it in the browser.

Can I embed it directly in an html file instead?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already find the how to, but otherwhise..
That's how i do it when i'm writing docs:

```
<pre class="mermaid">
  C4Component
    title component diags user story n1
    //*mermaid things*//
</pre>

   <script type="module">
    import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@9/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
    mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true});
    </script>
```